# Cannot edit main window jEdit

Tags: xml, edit, jedit

I can no longer edit the main window of jEdit 4.5.1 on OS X 10. java 1.6.0_29

The last file I was editing appears but I can't click it.  I'm using the XML plugin.

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling and rebooting, no results.

I've also tried to find the settings remove those and re-install but I'm no mac expert and am not sure how to find ~/.jedit

Comment: The jEdit directory under Mac OS X is `/Users/yourname/Library/jEdit`.

Comment: I should add that you might find the settings you're looking for in the `properties` file in that folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

latest update from Apple seemed to do the trick, problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

`~/.jedit` is probably in your Unix home directory. (sry, don't have a mac).

- [Open a terminal in OS X.](http://macapper.com/2007/03/08/the-terminal-an-introduction/)
- enter command: `cd ~/`
- move `~/.jedit` folder with `mv ~/.jedit ~/.jedit.bak`

If the `mv` command fails, then run a search for the `.jedit` folder on your entire machine with:

```
find / -type d -name .jedit
```

Good luck!